# CSS Div with accompanying Spans

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I'm trying to layout a simple three-column header, but something's not working quite right.

HTML (Ignore the horrible W3C uncompliance):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <span id="left">Page Title</span>
    <div id="center">Logged in as</div>
    <span id="right"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
padding: 6px;
background-color: #BBB;
}

#left {
float: left;
}

#center {
text-align: center;
}

#right {
float: right;
}
```

This almost works, except that #right drops down a line, and breaks the entire thing.
I'm not sure how to fix this, and I haven't done much layout with floating, so bear with me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the order of the elements. Have the floated right SPAN on top of the center DIV

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/htxFJ/

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the box model, you would know that this is the expected behaviour of an element with `display: block` -> default on a `div`.

Elements with `display: block` (block elements) behave like a rectangular block on the page, and expand horizontally to take up all available space. Hence they displace all subsequent elements to the next available space below them.

The same is not true with a `span`, which has `display: inline` set by default. Inline elements do not behave like "rectangles" -- they flow like text.

So in your situation you have a few options: like setting the width of the center `div` to a fixed value, or to a percentage. But that is not the correct way to fix the design. Take a look at a [few](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/three-fixed/) [three](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/three-liquid/) [column](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) layouts and study their html and css.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your "right" div so it is defined first:

```
<div id="header">
    <span id="right"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></span>
    <span id="left">Page Title</span>
    <div id="center">Logged in as</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the span `#center` is not floating. put it like the following:

```
#center {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because #center is then removed from the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><style>UR CSS</style><body><div id="header">

<span id="left">Page Title</span>
<div id="center">Logged in as
<span id="right"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></span>
</div>
```